# Are fixed points of automorphisms rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Fix an integer $d$ and a number field $K$ containing the $d$-th roots of unity. Let $X$ be a variety over $K$ such that $Aut(X / K)$ has an element $\varphi$ of order $d$. Is it true that the fixed points of $\varphi$ are $K$-rational?

Comment: No, that is not true.  Just consider the affine curve with equation $x^d + y^e=a$, for some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ and for some integer $e$ such that $K$ does not contain an $e^{\text{th}}$ root of $a$.  Let $\phi$ be the automporphism $\phi(x,y) = (\zeta\cdot x,y)$ where $\zeta$ is a specified primitive root of $1$.

Comment: Even more simply, take $K=\bf Q$, $d=2$, and $X$ the projective $x$-line with involution $\varphi: x \leftrightarrow a/x$ for some non-square $a$.